# How to select value on focus for a selectize?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, selectize.js

I want to select value on focus for [selectize](https://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/).

At this moment, I can just click and remove the value, but I want click(focus) should select all value strings of selectize element.

You could see how Google calendar works while creating new event.

[image]

On my side, if I click the time selectize element, then it should select all value strings and the selection can be removed or updated with new strings like Google.

[image]

My time selectize element is the following.

```
// php
<div class="select-beast is-hide-selectize-arrow select-event-time-end">
    <select name='event_time_end' class='control is-normal select-time' required>
         <?php echo TimeHelper::get_times(); ?>
    </select>
</div>

// php
function get_times ($default = '19:00', $interval = '+30 minutes') {

    $output = '';

    $current = strtotime('00:00');
    $end = strtotime('23:59');

    while ($current <= $end) {
        $time = date('H:i', $current);
        $sel = ($time == $default) ? ' selected' : '';

        $output .= "<option value=\"{$time}\"{$sel}>" . date('h:i A', $current) .'</option>';
        $current = strtotime($interval, $current);
    }

    return $output;
}

...
//jquery
<script>
    const $selected_time_start = $('.select-beast select[name="event_time_start"]').selectize({
         create: true
    });

    const selectize_event_start = $selected_time_start[0].selectize;
</script>
```

What I tried is to use focus event and [select method](https://api.jquery.com/select/) like the following.
But it didn't work.

```
$('.select-beast select[name="event_time_start"]').focus(function() { $(this).select(); } );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After research over 3 hours, I've found the most relative answer.

I need to update the selectize version to the latest and use `select_on_focus` plugin.

The plugin is here. https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/tree/master/src/plugins/select_on_focus

How to use:

If you are using jQuery, you can use standalone version of [selectize](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/selectize.js).

```
...
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.13.3/js/standalone/selectize.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.13.3/css/selectize.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  ...
  <select class="selectize"></select>
  ...
</body>
<script>
  const $selectize = $('.selectize').selectize({
    options: options,
    plugins: ['select_on_focus'],
    ...
  });
</script>
```

You see how to import the plugin, right?